# Codeigniter , hook not loading Input class correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

i'm having trouble with a simple hook in CI version 1.7.3.

i setted up a [pre_controller] hook in config hook.php file  and the hook code is:

```
class Cookie {

function remember_me(){

 $CI =& get_instance();
 if($CI->input->cookie('remember_me_id',true)){
   $CI->load->model('user');
   $user =  $CI->user->populateById($id = $CI->input->cookie('remember_me_id',true));
   if($user){
   if($CI->input->cookie('remember_me_token',true) == md5($user->email.$user->password)){
   $CI->bootstrap->setUserSession($user);
   }
  }
 }
}

}

//end class
```

the hook is loaded and executed but it doesn't load the input library cause it return error:
Call to a member function cookie() on a non-object

how can it be possible? could be possible that Input library is loaded after hooks is executed? :O
 ... cause in controllers,views and models input library works with no errors :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, the input class is not loaded at the `pre_controller` hook. You need to use the `post_controller_constructor` hook.

If that isn't early enough for you you will need to override the CI_Controller class itself.

Comment: i can't use cookies manipulation in post_controller cause it's too late :) cookies should be read pre_controller to process data :(

Comment: its post_controller_constructor, to be clear: that is before any actions in your controller are run but after everything is initialised. I guess you could access the $_COOKIE array directly but that is generally a good thing to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion is right. You'd be better off extending the Controller class and putting that code in the constructor of it. Make sure to let all your controllers extend your created class.

Fore more details see ['Extending Core Classes' in 1.7's User Guide](http://www.scribd.com/doc/53615007/CodeIgniter-User-Guide-1-7#outer_page_78)

Comment: ok but it's quite no sense that i can't manipulate cookies in hooks not? :/